# Espver V5 vs Esper 8.5 performace of loading statements

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, esper

We are using an executor service to load all statements in Esper runtime while server starts. Exact similar configurations are used(w.r.t. inbound thread pool param and everything else) in both version i.e. V5 and V8.5 but loading time in V8.5 is much more than earlier version. What could be the possible issue?

In esper 8.5 it is taking more than 20 minutes to load 3500+ statements whereas in esper 5 it was taking only 17 seconds.
Difference should not be this big. what could be the problem? Anything we are missing here?

Moreover while debugging more I found that compile and deploy method is taking more time among everything else.. compile method is taking 30 milliseconds to 4 seconds(approx.) for each statements and similarly deploy method also taking more time.

Answer (score 0):

In Esper 8 you can compile the statement into a binary, save the binary and load the binaries on startup. This is the recommended approach so that your application doesn't have to compile 3500+ statements all the time. Esper 8 can also compile in parallel.

Comment: I have couple of  question here - 
1. The time difference between esper 5 and esper 8 mentioned above is expected then? 2. "you can compile the statement into a binary, save the binary and load the binaries on startup" - how to achieve this? 3. Our requirement might not suite here to save the binary and load the binaries as our statement getting  changed at runtime by user. in that case what could be done?

Comment: 1. yes 2. http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.5.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#apicompiler-compiledio 3. cache the unchanged ones and parallel-compile the changed ones